# Create Wiki Posts?

Tags: support

Okay, I'm a total newbie, and just received the notification, "Congrats, you've gained the privilege – **create wiki posts** [learn more](https://apple.stackexchange.com/privileges/community-wiki)." Clicking on the "learn more" link brought me to the Create Wiki Posts FAQ, where the the question of *when* to create wiki posts was answered as follows: "When you feel your post would benefit from less concern about voting affecting the reputation of those participating in it."

Is it me, or is the tip offered here somewhat confusing? Is the author trying to say that a creating wiki post would lessen or remove any voting considerations a reader may have on the post? Or something else entirely?

Perhaps I need more time on this site, but as a newbie, this particular FAQ leaves me more confused than before I read it.

Answer (score 2):

Community Wiki questions continue to allow voting for semantic purposes (high value answers floating to the top), but forego all reputation benefits. Neither the asker nor answerers will receive reputation for upvotes, nor lose any for downvotes.

The FAQ is probably better worded as something along the lines of "… when a question has multiple correct answers, or will not benefit from reputation."

I think the r-word (reputation) was avoided to prevent people from avoiding Community Wiki questions so that they would continue to gain reputation.

Be sure to have a look through the [Community Wiki questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=wiki%3A1) on Ask Different as well.